# Any Suggestions for Ultra Edit Setup?

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, installation, text-editor, ultraedit

I was wondering if anyone uses Ultra Edit, I have just installed Version 16.30.0.1001.

My question is, can Ultra Edit be set-up to complete tags and to suggest attributes kind of like how dream weaver does?

Does anyone have any tips with Ultra Edit, anyway of making it work better for you?

I mostly use, coldfusion, jquery, css, html etc..

---

Thanks for the replies. Much Appreciated.

---

I'm very happy with notepad++ - its lightweight and the plug-in manager is great..

Comment: I take it you've looked here: http://www.ultraedit.com/downloads/extras.html ?

Comment: We bought UltraEdit at work - even after extensive fiddling and scripting, I just find Notepad++ more practical...

Comment: Any reason for choosing Ultra Edit as a ColdFusion editor? CF is kinda a niche and editors properly supporting CF generally need to be (or have a plugin) written with CF in mind, rather than keyword list files.

Comment: I use Homesite at work, but was looking for a good alternative at home, I'm looking for a program that is clean, simple and auto suggests/completes tags.. Ill have a look at Notepad++ :P thanks

Comment: I have to say /Notepad++ is very good..

Comment: i'd recommend sublime text 2 myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultraedit uses [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) and doing ctrl+space brings up possible code completions.